# Concatenate two more tables in power bi

Tags: concatenation, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have 3 tables in power bi e.g

**Table1**

```
name
Fan_count
connections.likes.id
connections.likes.name
connections.post.id
connections.post.name
```

and so on

**Table2**

```
name
Fan_count
connections.likes.id
connections.likes.name
connections.post.id
connections.post.name
```

and so on

**Table3**

```
name
Fan_count
connections.likes.id
connections.likes.name
connections.post.id
connections.post.name
```

and so on

for further kindly check attached power bi file

where i have 3 tables and all have same column name so i want to concatenate
these tables .. how i do this

check file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zxoyqr3le3qgdlc/social%20media.pbix?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Combine` -> `Append Queries` -> `Append Queries as New` to combine these tables into one:

[image]

This will make a new table, which will contain all rows from your source tables. In the dialog shown, select `Three or more tables` option and add your tables to the list:

[image]